# PXE boot Windows 7 repair disc from Linux server

Tags: linux, windows-7, pxe-boot

I have a Linux PXE server used to boot Clonezilla, Debian rescue, etc. on client machines when needed.

Is it possible to add the Windows 7 recovery CD (repair disc) to the available systems on this Linux PXE server?

I do NOT need to *install* Win7 over the network, and I don't have a WDS server. All I found were solutions for a full install (like [this](http://www.ultimatedeployment.org/win7pxelinux1.html) or [this](http://doomclaw.de/index.php/2009/08/18/installing-windows-7-with-a-pxe-boot-server/)). I am hoping that it can be much simpler in the case of the repair disc, which contains the following files:

```
\
 \boot\
    bcd                262'144 bytes 
    boot.sdi         3'170'304 bytes
    bootfix.bin          1'024 bytes
 \sources\
    boot.wim       369'906'796 bytes
 bootmgr               383'786 bytes
```

The Linux PXE server is also a Samba domain controller in case that makes a difference. And it is also the DHCP server of course.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you need:

```
\
 \boot\
  bcd
  boot.sdi
 \sources\
  boot.wim
 bootmgr.exe
 pxeboot.com
```

In DHCP you'll need to specify Option 66 `tftp_server.example.com` and Option 67 `pxeboot.com`.

Comment: I found pxeboot.com inside boot.wim. But my pxe server uses "pxelinux.0" (from Syslinux), so that is what the DHCP server specifies. And I don't know what to write into the "pxelinux.cfg/default" file. I guess tat the usual "kernel" and "append" lines wouldn't make much sense to Windows.